# Why is there a badge for down voting?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

I found some humor in that I can get a badge for down voting someone.

I try to look at the positive things in life.

It's a waste of energy looking for the negative.

I'm sure someone will down vote this so they can get that badge. :-)

Comment: On Meta other than the pop-up suggests downvotes also indicate disagreement. So downvotes on this question here mean that people prefer to keep a badge for downvoting or they believe downvotes are not a waste but an important contribution for the site.

Comment: "I found some humor in that I can get a badge for down voting someone" - we downvote posts, not people!

Comment: Semantics. People write posts.

Comment: "It's a waste of energy looking for the negative." really? so we should just let anyone post any crap and not close or remove posts? Then we could be the next Yahoo answers, I am sure that is what people want when they come here.

Comment: @MarkKirby go to g.ly/theY7X for some free stuff :p

Comment: @fixit7 it's not semantics. If we downvoted people, we would downvote all their posts, just because of who wrote it. We downvote posts on the main site which show a clear lack of research, and we downvote posts on Meta which we disagree with.

Answer (score 15):

Why shouldn't there be? There are badges for all other major moderation tasks (flagging, editing, *up*voting, deleting, reviewing), why should downvoting be exempt? Whatever you may think of it, downvoting is an important part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: We can agree to disagree. I have seen no down voting on other help sites.

Comment: The same badge exists on all Stack Exchange sites and has been given to thousands of users. Just your luck you haven't been downvoted on those, I suppose.

Comment: @fixit7 and that's precisely why most of them are flooded with irrelevant discussion and you need to wade through 12 pages of noise to find the one post that helps you. Downvoting is at least as important if not more important than upvoting. Downvoting wrong answers is essential, without that the whole site is useless.

Comment: (Did I say thousands? *Hundreds* of thousands, more like.)

Answer (score 11):

Agree 100% with @muru.  The only thing I'ld add is that downvoting is arguably even MORE important than upvoting in the answer sorting process.  There's also a badge for retracting a negatively received post/answer.

I have, in the past for example, gone through and started deleting all my 0 or negative answers or questions as site cleanup *assuming there's another more thorough answer present*.